# What kind of objects does enumerate returns in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, enumeration, enumerate

I'm reading python cookbook, it mentioned that enumerate() returns an iterator yielding all the pairs(two -item tuples) of the form(index, item)

And I can use d=dict(enumerate(L)) to make a dict.

For my understanding, I thought enumerate() returns a tuple. And dict() can make a tuple into dict.

So I tried:

```
dict((1,2))
```

TypeError pops out.

So I'm wondering what object did enumerate actually returns here which dict() can make it into a dict?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor accepts an `iterable` sequence of `key,value` pairs.

Your snippet `dict((1,2))` is not working because you are passing a tuple `(1,2)`, one `key,value` pair. It iterates over `(1,2)` and finds integers while expecting sequences.

Instead you should have passed a tuple containing one pair:

```
>>> dict(((1,2),))
{1: 2}
```

Or, for example, a list:

```
>>> dict([[1,2]])
{1: 2}
```

[`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an `enumerate` object, which is an iterator over sequence of tuple pairs:

```
>>> enumerate(range(10))
<enumerate object at 0x1059b0f50>
>>> list(enumerate(range(10)))
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 6), (7, 7), (8, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Hope that makes things more clear to you.

Comment: So, should I understand that enumerate returns something like ((0,item1))?

Comment: Besides, now I think I know how dict() works, it accept all kinds of paired data. Like [(1,2)] and even dict itself {1:2}.

Comment: @Zen good, enumerate returns an iterator over sequence of pairs - this is what dict accepts as an argument - that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's its own type:

```
>>> type(enumerate([]))
<class 'enumerate'>
```